# Qt_Creator close gui and run main.cpp

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a project and a basic app where there is a ui that pops up for users to enter data and then the data is uploaded to a firebase database. When I attempt to run the app the ui appears and i can enter in the data like in this image:

[image: App Ui]

Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include "checkinapp.h"
#include "databasehandler.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    checkinapp w;
    w.show();
    DatabaseHandler dbhandler;
    return a.exec();
}
```

The app gets stuck on `w.show()`. How can i make the submit button end `w.show()` and run the next line `DatabaseHandler dbhandler`

here is my checkinapp.h:

```
#ifndef CHECKINAPP_H
#define CHECKINAPP_H

#include <iostream>

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class checkinapp; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class checkinapp : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    checkinapp(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~checkinapp();

private slots:

    void on_happy_valueChanged(int value);

    void on_hungry_valueChanged(int value);

    void on_sleep_valueChanged(int value);

    void on_stress_valueChanged(int value);

    void on_male_toggled(bool checked);

    void on_female_toggled(bool checked);

    void on_other_toggled(bool checked);

    void on_help_toggled(bool checked);

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::checkinapp *ui;
};


#endif  // CHECKINAPP_H
```

checkinapp.cpp:

```
#include "checkinapp.h"
#include "ui_checkinapp.h"
#include "databasehandler.h"
#include "global_objects.hpp"
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QVariantMap>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

checkinapp::checkinapp(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::checkinapp)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
checkinapp::~checkinapp()
{
    if(help == 1)
    {
        //delete ui;
    }
    if(help == 1)
    {
        cout << "help";
    }
}

void checkinapp::on_happy_valueChanged(int value)
{
    happy = value;
}

void checkinapp::on_hungry_valueChanged(int value)
{
    hungry = value;
}


void checkinapp::on_sleep_valueChanged(int value)
{
    tired = value;
}


void checkinapp::on_stress_valueChanged(int value)
{
    stressed = value;
}


void checkinapp::on_male_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if(checked == true)
    {
        gender = 0;
    }
}

void checkinapp::on_female_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if(checked == true)
    {
        gender = 1;
    }
}

void checkinapp::on_other_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if(checked == true)
    {
        gender = 2;
    }
}

void checkinapp::on_help_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if(checked == true)
    {
        help = 1;
    }
}

void checkinapp::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    submitted = true;
        if(submitted==true)
        {
            cout <<submitted;
        }
    //delete ui;
}
```

databasehandler.h:

```
#ifndef DATABASEHANDLER_H
#define DATABASEHANDLER_H
#include <checkinapp.h>
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>

class DatabaseHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DatabaseHandler(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~DatabaseHandler();

public slots:
    void networkReplyReadyRead();


signals:

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager * m_networkManager;
    QNetworkReply * m_networkReply;

};

#endif // DATABASEHANDLER_H
```

databasehandler.cpp:

```
#include "checkinapp.h"
#include "databasehandler.h"
#include "global_objects.hpp"
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QVariantMap>
#include <iostream>


DatabaseHandler::DatabaseHandler(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    m_networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager ( this );
    QVariantMap newUser;
    newUser[ "Stress" ] = QString::number(stressed);
    newUser[ "Sleep" ] = QString::number(tired);
    newUser[ "Hungry" ] = QString::number(hungry);
    newUser[ "Happy" ] = QString::number(happy);
    newUser[ "Grade" ] = QString::number(grade);
    newUser[ "Date" ] = "1/10/21";
    newUser[ "Gender" ] = QString::number(gender);
    newUser[ "Aid" ] = QString::number(help);
    QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromVariant( newUser );
    QNetworkRequest newUserRequest( QUrl( "url/User.json"));
    newUserRequest.setHeader( QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QString( "application/json" ));
    m_networkManager->post( newUserRequest, jsonDoc.toJson() );
}
DatabaseHandler::~DatabaseHandler()
{
    m_networkManager->deleteLater();
}
void DatabaseHandler::networkReplyReadyRead()
{
    //qDebug() << m_networkReply->readAll();
}
```

Comment: You probably need to use your debugger. I don't believe the code should get stuck at show. Also I think your `DatabaseHandler` will read the global variables too soon. You probably want to get that out of main() and instead put that code in your `checkinapp` and remove the global variables.

Comment: For your application you probably wanted to make checkinapp a QDialog instead of a QMainWindow

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm, I don't know if stuck is the right word, when i press submit the window closes but the application doesnt make any submission to the database. I initially thought it was reading the variables too soon, but i tested and if the variables are not defined the app should still make a submission to the database just with all 0's but the app isn't submitting anything.

Comment: I will give the QDialog a try, but like i said this is y first time using qt and c++.

Comment: I believe your initial thought is correct. As for the submission part you may want to test that code without the GUI at all. Just put fixed values in the variables and debug the submission.

Comment: I have done exactly that, i have tested both parts independently. I tested with cout and the GUI does edit the global variables. and when i make the variabled fixed amounts and run just the submission it works perfectly

Comment: The issue is when I press submit the app keeps running, but I don't know what its doing. It doesn't run the database submission code but it closes the GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think you have some confusion. w.show() makes the window appear. That's it. Execution continues all the way to your a.exec().

What you need to do is have your window tell your `DatabaseHandler` when it's time to grab values and do an update. The Qt way is to set up a signal. I find those to kind of be a pain, so I use dependency injection. That is, I'd create the handler earlier in main but NOT have the constructor do all that. Make a method. Then pass a reference to the handler in the constructor of the window.

Then when the button is clicked, call a method on the handler to do its job. After that, you can close the app if you want.

Comment: Thank you, ill have to give that a try. However, i dont know what any of that means as ive just started with c++ but hopefully there are some youtube videos explaining it.